# SQS consumer in different aws account:The specified Queue does not exist for the wsdl version

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-ec2, apache-camel, amazon-sqs

I have a SQS consumer that runs in ec2 of different vpc/account and the SQS is on the different account. I have created a new policy and added to the IAM role which is applied at my ec2. 
When I run the consume at my local machine, I am able to read the SQS messages but when I do it from ec2, it throws below error

```
HTTPStatusCode: 400 AmazonErrorCode: AWS.SimpleQueueService.NonExistentQueue
com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.QueueDoesNotExistException: The specified queue does not exist for this wsdl version. (Service: AmazonSQS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AWS.SimpleQueueService.NonExistentQueue;
```

When I create the SQS under the same aws account where my consumer is running, I am able to read the SQS. Is there anything I am missing here?

Comment: If you need connect to queue across accounts, you must specify correct `queueOwnerAWSAccountId` and `region` in route URI. Have you? If yes, post your actual route please.

Comment: @Bedla: I have specified correct region in code. accountId was part of my policy which is added to my IAM role. Because of the security issues, I can post the queue details